# Connected open subset after piercing the set

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

Let D be a domain in $\mathbb{C}$, thus a connected open subset of the complex numbers. Suppose we remove one point of it no matter which one. Is D without this point still connected?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** In $\mathbb C$ an open set is connected if and only if it is path connected.

**Hint 2** Lets call the point you remove $a$. If $P$ is a path from $x$ to $y$ in $D$ passing via $a$, use the fact that there exists some $r$ such that $\{ z: |z-a|< r \} \subset D$ to construct a path from $x$ to $y$ in $D$ not passing through $a$.

Comment: Thank you for your help.